# Fourier Transformation and Reverse FT of the delta function

Tags: fourier-transform, epsilon-delta

FT of the $\delta(t)$:

$$\delta(\omega)=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}\delta(t)e^{i\omega t}dt=\frac 1 {2\pi}$$

The RFT:

$$\delta(t)=\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \delta(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega=\frac 1{2\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} e^{-i\omega t}d\omega $$

Then the following is written:

$$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}e^{i\omega t}dt=2\pi\delta(\omega)$$

Where does this last equation comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The $\delta(\omega)$ in your final formula is not the $\delta(\omega)$ in your first formula, but instead is the $\delta(t)$ in your second formula with $t$ replaced by $\omega$. Just take your second formula and swap every $t$ and $\omega$ and multiply by $2\pi$.

It is not great notation to use the same symbol for a function and its Fourier transform. Instead of $\delta(\omega)$ it might be helpful to write

$$\hat\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ ,$$ or $$\mathcal{F}[\delta](\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ .$$

Comment: if i substitute $t$ with $\omega$ in the 2nd eq. I still have a problem: the power in the exponential in my 2nd eq. is $-i\omega t$ while in the last eq. it's $i\omega t$. Simply substituting  $t$ with $\omega$ doesn't change the sign And you would also get $\omega^2$ if you would do the substitution.

Comment: True, but $\delta(t)=\delta(-t)$. So then just replace $t$ by $-t$ to get the right sign under the integral. And it isn't just substituting $t$ with $\omega$. You should also change the integration variable from $\omega$ to $t$. Then there won't be any $\omega^2$.